# Panels don't change

Tags: unity-game-engine

After I saved each panel to a lvl, I get 50 levels but panels just change from level 1 to 4, then I get some issues with the code, what should I change or do?
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mxe9L.png) [button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRJVc.png) [level](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Eb6D.png) [error again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6Ms6.png)

```css
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class ButtonChange : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
   
   public void changemenuscene(int scenename)
 {
  SceneManager.LoadScene(scenename);
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Application.LoadLevel is obsolete.
Try to use something like
SceneManager.LoadScene

Comment: my levels are in building settings but unity don't see them

Comment: try to load the scene 7 directly (you can try by index and by name) and see if this time it works. If it works debug every scene at runtime (put a break point in the scene load line in visual studio, connect to unity also in visual studio and in unity click the play button... everytime you call the scene load line the program will stop and you will be able to tell what is inside your scenename).

Answer (score 0):

Do all buttons in all levels contain the reference to que script that changes levels?